# Need help on how to invoke a .sed file from within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a series of sed commands to redact a file. The sed file is named cmdfile.sed. Everything works as expected when I run "sed -f cmdfile.sed redactme.txt". I need to create a bash file named assign2.bash that simply invoke the .sed file when I type a filename into the command line as an argument to the bash file.

I created a bash file named "assign2.bash". This is what I have for it so far:

```
#! /bin/bash
# assign2

(
while [true]{

do 

sh cmdfile.sed
}
done
)
```

And this is the cmdfile.sed:

```
#cmdfile
/^.*..DL [0-9]/ s/[0-9]/X/g   #redacts sensitive information in the file
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//18
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//17
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//16
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//15
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//14
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//13
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//12
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//11
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//10
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//9
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//8
/^.*..DL XXXXXX*/ s/X//7
/^.*TXDL XXXXX/ s/X{5}/XXXXXX/g
/5[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}/ s/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})/MC-\4/g
/6[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}/ s/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})/DISC-\4/g
/4[0-9]{15}/ s/([0-9]{12})([0-9]{4})/VISA-\2/g
/37[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{5}/ s/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{6})-([0-9]{1})([0-9]{4})/AMEX-\4/g
/34[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{5}/ s/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{6})-([0-9]{1})([0-9]{4})/AMEX-\4/g
/TX.[A-Z]{2}..[0-9]{3}.*/ s/TX.[A-Z]{2}..[0-9]{3}./TX XXXXXX/g
/TX.[A-Z0-9]{2}..[A-Z0-9]{2}.*/ s/TX.[A-Z0-9]{2}..[A-Z0-9]{2}./TX XXXXXX/g

s/<orgname>/City of Gainsville, Florida/g


It should redact the information in the .txt file in the same as it does when I run sed with the -f option in the terminal. However, when I run ./assign2.bash redactme.txt , it returns the following error:

./assign2.bash: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./assign2.bash: line 10: `}'
```

Comment: Delete everything after line 2 of that shell script and replace it with `sed -f cmdfile.sed "$1"`

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'm making progress now for sure since I can see lines from the redactme.txt being printed on the screen. But after every line it prints out it says "sh: 1: xit: not found". My .sed and .bash files are both in the same directory.

Comment: Ahh, nvmnd. I had added 'exit' to the end of my .sed script, which messed me up! Thank you so much for help! XD I truly appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you used the wrong interpreter:

> ```
> sh cmdfile.sed
> ```

You need to use `sed`:

```
sed -f cmdfile.sed
```

Don't forget to provide it with some input.

Even easier is to make the sed script executable, and give it a shebang line at the beginning:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
```

Then you can directly execute it - no need for a shell script.